# Is it possible to change the size of Heiro generated font in the code?-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I am using a font generated by Heiro tool.

```
game.scoreFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/score.fnt"), false);
```

I applied it for a label;

```
private void drawScore() {
        Label.LabelStyle scoreStyle = new Label.LabelStyle();// style
        scoreStyle.font = game.scoreFont;   
        scoreLabel2 = new Label(scoreController.getScoreString(), scoreStyle);// label
        scoreLabel2.setPosition(scoreBox.getX()+scoreBox.getWidth()/2.7f,scoreBox.getY()+scoreBox.getHeight()/2);
        scoreLabel2.setAlignment( Align.center);
    }
```

While generating font,I gave a size of 32.
But same font I want to use for a label somewhere else in the game ,with a little bit bigger size.

Is it possible to increase the size then?or Should I generate a new font of required size with Heiro tool again?

Comment: Consider using "Shoebox" instead of Heiro: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxPf1M7YORU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale your `BitmapFont` by

```
bitmapFont.getData().setScale(2);
```

and then use this font in `LabelStyle`, however you can also scale in this way

```
labelStyle.font.getData().setScale(2);
```

It works on reference of `BitmapFont`so it scaled everywhere, where you're using that `BitmapFont` in your game.

So you can create two object of `BitmapFont` with same file and scale one font and use where you want bigger font.

---

I'll recommend you to create two font with different size using your tools. Scaling is never a good solution.